# Trick sonar into ignoring commented code

Tags: sonarqube

I was wondering if there is a way to trick sonar into neglecting commented out code while still keeping it inside. I would like to leave the snippet of code in there for modifications at a later date but would also like to increase compliance.

I have this for example
`// bdgItems.setGpIncrease(zero);` and this is where i get compliance issuses. on the other hand regular comments like `// get data points` is no cause for issue. I'd like to keep the commented code in there to pick up where I left off in the next cycle of development, but like i said, reduce the issues. Ive tried a few ways in tricking it like `// [DELETE THIS] bdgItems.setGpIncrease(zero);` or `// bdgItems . setGpIncrease ( zero );` with spaces in between words but it still knows! I was wondering if some of you vets knew any tricks [i'm fairly new to sonar].

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with sonar, buy I'm guessing it considers invalid code as comments.
What happens when you do something like they do with email addresses where it's written as `foo [at] bar [dot] com`?
It's a little more work to undo, but it may make the code invalid enough to consider.

Comment: hadn't though of that. Applied change and submitted to Sonar. Will check back in in 10 min or so

Comment: nope didnt work :p thanks for the response tho

Answer (score 2):

### *It's not recommended, as Mithfindel already advised.*

Simply replace dots and semi-colons with underscore.

---

Code sample: `documentClient.deleteDatabase("dbs/" + DATABASE_ID, null);`

The resulting comment without the warning would be: `// documentClient_deleteDatabase("dbs/" + DATABASE_ID, null)_`

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical technical debt management issue.

If you "leave it there for later", then you are indeed adding technical debt into your source code, that you intend on repaying later. So SonarQube flagging this commented out code as issues is intended behavior.

You still have the option to flag those issues as false positives, but I do believe you should keep them as true issues, if only to remind yourself of coming back to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

With C# **omitting the semicolon at the end of a line tricks Sonar** (May also work for other languages).

This emits the `S125: Remove this commented out code` warning:

```cs
// string name = "Mustafa";
```

But this removes the warning:

```cs
// string name = "Mustafa"
```

Actually Sonar's detection of commented out code is based on heuristics and hence does not work perfectly. What about this one?

```
// This Line Is Not Code;
```

This line *does* emit the `S125` warning.

On the other hand, **I don't recommend suppressing or tricking** this warning since leaving code in comments bloats source code, obstructs readability and sometimes confuses developers, wasting their time.

One last point is that commenting out code may have its place. I tend to leave some *visualization code* in the comments with graphics programming as a *debugging aid*. For instance, in some graphics computations, displaying an interim shape on the screen may help verify that its coordinates or size are computed correctly. But those commented-out codes probably do not exceed %0.1 in all comments.

Answer (score 0):

In the console, right click on the message, select deactivate this rule and reload window.